# Use VBA to search text file for string and return line number

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2007, vba

I'm trying to search through a txt file for a certain string using a Do While Not EOF loop and then either return or just set a flag of that line number whenever the string is found.

I'm extremely new to VBA with access. What would be the most basic way to go about doing this? I'm using Access 2007

Thank you

Here is what I have so far, I pulled it from various examples online to try to get it to work.

```
    Dim myFile As String
   Dim text As String
   Dim textline As String
   Dim posIAV As Integer

   myFile = "file path"

   Open myFile For Input As #1

   Do While Not EOF(1)
   Line Input #1, textline
   text = text & textline

   Loop

   Close #1

   posIAV = InStr(text, "IAVs ADDED in this release include")

   MsgBox (posIAV)
```

Comment: I see you have a `Do While Not EOF` loop.  Could you show us what you've tried?

Comment: Sure, just added what I have so far in the OP

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just replace **MyString** below with whatever it is you're looking for.

```
   Dim myFile As String
   Dim text As String
   Dim textline As String
   Dim posIAV As Integer
   Dim Ctr as Integer
   Dim Ctr2 as Integer

   myFile = "file path"
   Ctr = 0
   Ctr2 = 0

   Open myFile For Input As #1

   Do While Not EOF(1)
   Line Input #1, textline
   text = text & textline

   ' Increment Ctr since you're on the line now
   Ctr = Ctr + 1

   ' Check the current line to see if it contains the string we're looking for
   ' If it does, set Ctr2 to be the current line number
   If textline like "*MyString*" Then
      Ctr2 = Ctr
   End If

   Loop

   Close #1

   posIAV = InStr(text, "IAVs ADDED in this release include")

   MsgBox (posIAV)
```

Comment: Could it possibly be missing something after the If...like? I get an error message saying "expected: Then or GoTo"

Comment: The code is missing `Then` after `"*MyString*"`. I added it.

Comment: Perfect! Thank you both.

I'm a bit all over the place when learning VBA, do either of you guys know of any good online tutorials or literature for me to use for future reference? Some of my future tasks will include parsing a txt file and having it saved to a table that I created in Access

Comment: I can see you're new here, so I'd just like to point out that if the answer worked, please consider upvoting it or giving it the green checkmark so any future visitors will know it's correct.  Thanks!

Comment: I don't really know any good websites, but I know a lot of people here know their stuff and can probably help you with other questions.