# Search a string and return line number VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I am very new here and to VBA Excel programming. I have a text file with x,y,z coordinates for some points. It also has some unwanted infos at the beginning. My required info comes only at line number say 20 after the string '1-xxx'.  My code is to open this file, go through line by line, search for the string '1-xxx' and return the line number. This line number output is then given as input to a recorded macro below in the field '.TextFileStartRow'. I have searched in internet and wrote somethin like this. But the problem is i get only the character postion of the searched text and not the line number as i expected. Where am i going wrong ?

```
    Sub Macro()

    Dim Pos_rw As Integer, text As String, textline As String
    Dim folder As String, StartingDir As String
    Dim file
    StartingDir = ThisWorkbook.Path
    ChDir StartingDir
    file = Application.GetOpenFilename("Text Files (*.txt), *.txt")
    Open file For Input As #1
    Do Until EOF(1)
     Line Input #1, textline
     text = text & textline
    Loop
    Close #1
    Pos_rw = InStr(text, "1-xxx")

    With ActiveSheet.QueryTables _
        .Add(Connection:="TEXT;" & file, Destination:=Range("$D$2:$F$26"))
        .FieldNames = True
        .RowNumbers = False
        .FillAdjacentFormulas = False
        .PreserveFormatting = True
        .RefreshOnFileOpen = False
        .RefreshStyle = xlOverwriteCells
        .SavePassword = False
        .SaveData = True
        .AdjustColumnWidth = True
        .RefreshPeriod = 0
        .TextFilePromptOnRefresh = False
        .TextFilePlatform = 1252
        .TextFileStartRow = Pos_rw
        .TextFileParseType = xlDelimited
        .TextFileTextQualifier = xlTextQualifierDoubleQuote
        .TextFileConsecutiveDelimiter = False
        .TextFileTabDelimiter = False
        .TextFileSemicolonDelimiter = False
        .TextFileCommaDelimiter = False
        .TextFileSpaceDelimiter = False
        .TextFileOtherDelimiter = ":"
        .TextFileColumnDataTypes = Array(9, 9, 1, 1, 1)
        .TextFileTrailingMinusNumbers = True
        .Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
  End With
```

Comment: Maybe [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23371031/6706419)? (As stated in link provided here and below, add a counter to your loop)

Comment: In your loop you can count the number of lines. for each loop add 1 to a counter and if `InStr(textline, "1-xxx")` bigger than 0 you have the line number

Answer (score 1):

The solution is to keep track of the line number in the loop, which should terminate as soon as you found the line that you are looking for:

```
Sub Macro()
    Dim Pos_rw As Long
    Dim textline As String
    Dim folder As String, StartingDir As String
    Dim found As Boolean

    Dim file
    StartingDir = ThisWorkbook.Path
    ChDir StartingDir
    file = Application.GetOpenFilename("Text Files (*.txt), *.txt")
    Open file For Input As #1

    Do Until EOF(1) or found
        Pos_rw = Pos_rw + 1
        Line Input #1, textline
        If InStr(textline, "1-xxx") > 0 Then found = True
    Loop
    Close #1
    'the rest of your logic, including some safety code if found = False here
End Sub
```

A small point: I changed `Dim Pos_rw As Integer` to `Dim Pos_rw As Long`. There is almost never a good reason to use `Integer` in modern VBA (unless you are somehow or other running it on a 16-bit processor). You are risking overflow for no good reason.